# Verificar palavras em Array php

Tags: php

Estou montando um verificador de texto, onde eu armazeno em ***array1*** diversos textos (não consegui filtrar eles) e no ***array2*** eu coloco determinadas palavras para serem comparadas. Assim, deve-se verificar se as palavras que estão no ***array2***, se encontram no ***array1***, para poder se determinar do que se trata o texto.

```
<?PHP
$array1 = explode("", file_get_contents('cotidiano.txt'));
$array2 = explode("", file_get_contents('palavras.txt'));
?>
```

Texto exemplo:
O texto vem da seguinte maneira:

```
TEXTO1
<head> <edic><Diário Gaúcho 12/05/2013</edic>
<autor>Denise Waskow, denise.waskow@diariogaucho.com.br</autor>
</head>
<body>
<subtítulo>Para celebrar</subtítulo>
<título>Mães e filhos se divertem em atividades culturais no Parque da Redenção</título>
Jogos de mesa, futebol, brinquedos infláveis, teatro, dança e uma série de outras brincadeiras movimentaram o domingo no parque
Criançada aproveitou o domingo nos brinquedos
Denise Waskow
denise.waskow@diariogaucho.com.br
Se existe algo que deixa toda mãe realizada é ver que o filho está feliz. E quem levou a prole neste domingo à Redenção ganhou esse presente para celebrar o Dia das Mães. 
Jogos de mesa, futebol, brinquedos infláveis, teatro, dança e uma série de outras brincadeiras movimentaram o domingo, em uma ação promovida pela Secretaria Municipal de Esporte, Recreação e Lazer da Capital. A gurizada aproveitou muito, e as mamães se emocionaram com a alegria deles.
<subtítulo>Diversão nos brinquedos</subtítulo>
Enquanto a pequena Amanda, três anos, criava coragem para descer no tobogã inflável, a mãe, a babá Roselaine Pereira, 30 anos, ficava na parte de baixo do brinquedo, incentivando a menina a descer, fotografando e se divertindo junto.  
- É maravilhoso, é ótimo. O melhor presente é isso, a felicidade deles - derrete-se.
O filho mais velho, Jhonattan, 13 anos, já não está mais na fase de brincar, mas nem por isso deixou de acompanhar a mãe. Enquanto a irmã caçula passava de um brinquedo para o outro, ele contou como homenageou Roselaine no início do domingo: 
- Eu disse que eu amo ela.
<subtítulo>Uma torcida especial</subtítulo>
"Vai Joana, vai Joana!". Ao lado do espaço demarcado para o futebol, a massoterapeuta Tânia Regina Horta, 46 anos, incentivava a filha caçula, de seis anos, no esporte. E apesar de a mãe ser gremista e a filha colorada, não existe rivalidade. O que conta nessa relação, claro, é o amor. 
- A mãe que está sendo homenageada e são os filhos que se divertem. Está ótimo, o melhor é curtir a companhia deles - elogia. 
Depois de uma manhã inteira de brincadeiras, o planejamento de Tânia era encontrar os dois filhos mais velhos, além dos dois enteados, para o tradicional almoço de Dia das Mães.
</body>
```

**Minha dúvida seria :** Como realizar a verificação de dados em diferentes arrays (ou o que for necessário implementar) para se determinar do que se trata o texto?! Não conheço muito da linguagem e por isso fiquei em dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se a palavra existe no Array:

```
$texto1 = preg_replace("<(.|\n)*?>","",file_get_contents('cotidiano.txt'));
$array1 = explode("",$texto1);
$array2 = explode("", file_get_contents('palavras.txt'));

foreach($array2 as $valor){
   if(in_array($valor, $array1){
     echo "$valor Existe !";
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
Adicionado trecho para remover o html.
Só cuidado, pois a função vai remover tudo que estiver entre `<>`

Comment: Ótimo! Dessa maneira eu iria conseguir percorrer todas as palavras do texto? Pois o arquivo que acaba sendo lido, contém mais ou menos 150 textos na mesma formatação que esse colocado como exemplo.

Comment: Ele vai percorrer todas as palavras que estão no "array 2" e verificar se ela existe no "array 1", a quantidade de texto depende de como você populou o array

Comment: Sim, no caso o "array2" contém as palavras "chaves" e no "array1" contém o texto com esse padrão. Tem alguma maneira de filtrar e separar os textos do array1? Tipo, o texto principal começa após a tag ***</titulo>*** e termina antes do ***</body>***.

Comment: @user56742 editado